# How to create new thread in AcceptCallBack when socket created In Ios

Tags: ios, sockets, cocos2d-x

I want create socket to connect multi device, and i have a accept call back function

```
void AcceptCallBack(
                    CFSocketRef socket,
                    CFSocketCallBackType type,
                    CFDataRef address,
                    const void *data,
                    void *info)
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFIndex bytes;
    UInt8 buffer[128];
    UInt8 recv_len = 0, send_len = 0;

    /* The native socket, used for various operations */
    CFSocketNativeHandle sock = *(CFSocketNativeHandle *) data;

    /* The punch line we stored in the socket context */
    char *punchline = info;

    /* Create the read and write streams for the socket */
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, sock,
                                 &readStream, &writeStream);

    if (!readStream || !writeStream) {
        close(sock);
        fprintf(stderr, "CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket() failed\n");
        return;
    }

    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
    CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

    /* Wait for the client to finish sending the joke; wait for newline */
    // How to create a new IOS thread from here to read data from client.

}
```

I want create NSThread for listening data from Client. Because this is an C++ function i can not access a variable from Object C.
Thanks.

Comment: Was the answer below helpful or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

1. You can write an objective C helper function in a new .mm file, and call it from your C++ code
2. You can change the C++ file to have a .mm extension. That way you can mix Objective C code in with the C++. You will probably need some include magic such as this at the top of the file:-

`#ifdef __OBJC__
    // prevent C++ compiler errors
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #endif`

3.You should also look at using GCD instead. That uses a C interface, and it may be possible to do everything you need using `dispatch_async()`. Because `dispatch_async()` uses blocks, you would need to set the `-fblocks` compiler flag if you were still using a .cpp file extension.